# qmtest not running on CENTOS. build on Mac OS x

Tags: python, linux, frameworks, centos

I downloaded qmtest for Mac OS X, and build and installed it on MAc OS-X m/c and then copied the relevant site-packages/binary file into CENT-OS m/c so that I could run qmtest from cENT-os m/c.

But an error that I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/qmtest", line 74, in <module>
    import qm.test.cmdline
  File "/data/build/spike/python/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qm/test/cmdline.py", line 20, in <module>
    import base
  File "/data/build/spike/python/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qm/test/base.py", line 483, in <module>
    import qm.host
  File "/data/build/spike/python/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qm/host.py", line 18, in <module>
    from   qm.executable import RedirectedExecutable
  File "/data/build/spike/python/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qm/executable.py", line 41, in <module>
    import qm.sigmask
ImportError: /data/build/spike/python/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qm/sigmask.so: invalid ELF header
```

As the m/c where I want to run qmtest is CENTOS type, so how could i remove this error, or where can i get the version of QMTEST for centos m/c so that i could copy relevant files over there, and then work it out.

qmtest is running perfectly on MacOS X m/c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take the source for QMTest and build it on CentOS itself.

CentOS and Mac are not binary compatible.